# android: findViewById returns NULL when accesses from another class

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I have a MainActivity.class on which I do setContentView, here are the three variables I used to

```
    EditText labelText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.label_field);
    EditText phoneText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_field);
    Spinner deviceTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.device_type_spinner);
    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button)
```

Now, I have a separate class which extends an async task, I am trying to modify the above fields from the async task(class located in another file).

In order to do this, I am passing the context of the activity to async task and doing the steps below

```
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;
            Button buttonRegister =(Button)activity.findViewById(R.id.register_button);
            EditText labelText = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.label_field);

            buttonRegister.setEnabled(true);
            labelText.setFocusable(true);
```

but the buttonRegister returns null and the app crashes, can anybody tell me where have I gone wrong,

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at        com.yantranet.minixagent.requests.DeviceCreateRequest$1.onClick(DeviceCreateRequest.java:237)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is the asynctask class in main class or different?

Comment: do you pass the activity context to the asynctask constructor?

Comment: @Stacks28 : it is in another class

Comment: @Raghunandan : Yes, I am passing the activity context. I have tried to debug it, and the context is being passed.

Comment: @Code_Yoga post the stack trace. also are you doing the updation of ui in doInbackground?

Comment: if you are passing context then why are you creating new object of Main Activity?? use context instead.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger :if I try to use context, then I get 'cannot resolve method 'findViewById'

Comment: @Raghunandan : I have added the trace above

Comment: @Code_Yoga post your DeviceCreateRequest.java. and your asynctask code full.

Comment: are you doing this inside doInBackground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the buttonRegister returns null and the app crashes, can anybody
>   tell me where have I gone wrong,

i don't see where you are calling

```
setContentView(<layout>);
```

method. Without it, it always returns **`NPE`** because this method cares about inicialisation of all UI instances in specified layout. You have to call it always before you want to initialise widgets with

```
findViewById(<id>);
```

Since you are calling it in another class it won't work (class know nothing about what you did in other class). You need to:

- pass widgets via some constructor
- change application logic (most likely is not designated correctly)

Comment: I have already set the content view in the Main Activity, do I have to set content view again from sync task to access the fields?

Comment: You should pass widgets via constructor or make class as inner class.

Comment: I have set content view again from the asynctask like u said, and it works fine now. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the correct activity context then it should work, But I would prefer not to pass context to another class as it has nothing to with activity. You can use the following design.

1. Register a listener with async class
2. Implement that listener in activity
3. Once async task completes it's work it will invoke that listener
4. Activity will change the UI whatever it want upon listener execution.

Comment: I am actually calling an alert dialog from the onPostExecute of the async task and from the dialog, I am trying to update the Activity GUI

Comment: Please post complete code , I'd like to see what context are you passing to async task and what context are you using to update UI.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify layout elements inside doInBackgroud().

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

}
```

You can use `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute(String result)` to modify layout elements.

Now, I suggest you to override onPostExecute() in the same class where you call AsyncClass execute.
ex:-

```
new MyLoadAsync(Inbox.this){
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Inbox.this);//////////
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if(result!=null){

                }
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }


        }.execute("your_param");
```

So, here you can access your layout params .

Comment: Yes, I am doing it from onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good way to do, But if you want to access the widgets of other activity then you should make getter setter for it.

```
//In you mainActivity
public Button getRegisterButton()
{
     //Return register button here.
     return btn;
}
public EditText getFieldEditText()
{
      //Return editText here;
      return eText;
}
```

Code where you want this view.

//In Current Activity.

```
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;
            Button buttonRegister =activity.getRegisterButton();
            EditText labelText = activity.getFieldEditText();
         if(buttonRegister != null)
         {
            buttonRegister.setEnabled(true);
         }
         if(labelText != null)
         {
            labelText.setFocusable(true);
         }
```

Hope that this will helpful.